# Why will Clojure accept this when entered into a REPL, but not when written as a function?

Tags: clojure

I have been writing a fairly simple piece of code to get the hang of Clojure and I've run into an issue where when I pass each line into a REPL in order (while using a test case to substitute the values that would be passed as part of the function), I get the expected result but when I try to compile it as a function I get the error `Execution error (ClassCastException) at testenv.core/sum-of-two-largest-squares (core.clj:14). class clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (clojure.lang.PersistentList and clojure.lang.IFn are in unnamed module of loader 'app')` 
The relevant function is as follows (note that I've moved each step into variables in order to figure out the problem)

```
(defn sum-of-two-largest-squares [a b c]
     (
      (def x (into () (map math/abs [a b c])))
      (def m (apply min x))
      (def y (into () (map square (remove (fn [n] (= n m)) x))))
      (apply + y)
     )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just put parenthesis around things without expecting it to change the meaning.

What works when run in a REPL is:

```
(defn abs [n] (java.lang.Math/abs n))
(defn square [n] (* n n))

(def x (into () (map abs [a b c])))
(def m (apply min x))
(def y (into () (map square (remove (fn [n] (= n m)) x))))
(apply + y)
```

...and *strictly*, this still works if injected into a function, as long as you take out the extra parenthesis (though it works slowly and with unwanted side effects due to the inappropriate use of `def`):

```
(defn sum-of-two-largest-squares [a b c]
  (def x (into () (map abs [a b c])))
  (def m (apply min x))
  (def y (into () (map square (remove (fn [n] (= n m)) x))))
  (apply + y)
)
(sum-of-two-largest-squares a b c)
```

However, a *good-practice* alternative would use `let` instead:

```
(defn abs [n] (java.lang.Math/abs n))
(defn square [n] (* n n))

(defn sum-of-two-largest-squares [a b c]
     (let [x (into () (map abs [a b c]))
           m (apply min x)
           y (into () (map square (remove (fn [n] (= n m)) x)))]
       (apply + y)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a more typical solution to this problem

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn square [x] (* x x))
(defn sum-of-two-largest-squares [a b c]
  (let-spy
    [sorted      (sort [a b c])
     largest-two (rest sorted)
     squares     (mapv square largest-two)
     result      (apply + squares)]
    result))

(dotest
  (is= 41 (spyx (sum-of-two-largest-squares 3 4 5)))
  )
```

with result:

```
-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 15.0.2
-----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
sorted => (3 4 5)
largest-two => (4 5)
squares => [16 25]
result => 41
(sum-of-two-largest-squares 3 4 5) =>  41

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

It uses [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  Just change `let-spy` back to `let` once finished writing/debugging.